# Affect of mod_rewrite on links without a forward slash?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite

I have the below VirtualHost and HTML.  The purpose of the VirtualHost is to take http://example.com/bla/index.php?id=3 and rewrite it as http://example.com/index.php?admin=bla&id=3.  If the URL in the browser is http://example.com/bla/, both the form and the links go to http://example.com/bla/index.php.  But if I put http://example.com/bla (without the trailing forward slash) in the browser, the posts go to http://example.com/bla/index.php, but the the links go to http://example.com/index.php (without the "bla").  Why is this, and what do I do to direct the links to http://example.com/bla/index.php?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        allow from all
        Options +Indexes
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        # If the request is for a valid directory, file, or link, don't do anything
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]

        RewriteRule ^([^/]*|[^/]+/(index.php)?)$ /index.php?admin=$1 [L,QSA]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Links</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="index.php?id=1">link 1</a>
        <a href="index.php?id=2">link 2</a>
        <a href="index.php?id=3">link 3</a>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" name="post_text">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `+/(index.php)?` only makes index.php optional while still expecting the url to end in a slash. I'm no reg-expert but wouldn't you just have to put a ? after that first slash - `+/?(index.php)?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a problem or a bug.

**With the link the browser does the job**

With `http://example.com/bla` :
The link `index.php`
in the root folder -> `http://example.com/index.php`

With `http://example.com/bla/` :
The link `index.php`
in the `bla` folder -> `http://example.com/bla/index.php`

**With the form the server does the job**

The browser send form to `http://example.com/bla` or `http://example.com/bla/` and the server rewrite.

You can use this in your html:

```
    <a href="/bla/index.php?id=3">link 3</a>
    <form method="post" action="/bla/index.php">
```

or in the head:

```
  <base href="/bla/">
```

to avoid problems

Comment: I would rather not hardcode all the links.  I've never heard of `<base>`.  Is this often the preferred solution?  THank you

Comment: Yes, `<base>` is a good solution. It's possible to add the `/`with `.htaccess` for all not valid link

Comment: Thank you for teaching me `<base>`!  I just tested it and it seems to work.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked. We learn every day! (especially me) ;-)